# Magento product won't display on search. Search returned count of results

Tags: magento

I have already checked the following list

```
•   Stock
•   Visibility
•   Status
•   Selected Categories
•   Website
```

but the specific product wouldn't still display on search. The search displayed count of items though.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hv0gifv8syrigf2/magentoproduct_nosearchresult.png

Kindly help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Actually it seems that your search returned 1 item. But probably an error was generated but maybe you couldn't see it maybe because you're not in dev mode. Thus magento doesnt show some of the error on frontend.

Try looking at the page source in your browser (Ctrl + U) at the end of it and see if you find an exception or an error trace, and also try adding `SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"` to your .htaccess and refresh the page to see errors (if there are any).

Cheers

Comment: He should also uncomment the line `ini_set("display_errors",1);` in `index.php`.  This will turn on php error messages so he can view them in the page source.

Comment: I just looked at the page source on the search page and I saw at the bottom a broken image link: "<img src=". How should I fix this?

Comment: If you created a template then there probably is an error in it. Try seanbreeden suggestions as well and see if something comes out. There is probably an error in some of the template files you changed (first guess would be catalog/product/list.phtml)